# Open a std::vector<int> in Excel from memory heap without serializing?

Tags: c++, excel

If I have a vector of int in memory, is there a way to pass this to Excel?  Currently the only way I know is to write the data to file as a csv, then pass the saved file to excel to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the only *direct* connection would be using a DDE link.

Now I don't usually recommend that, as it is a bit of an aged technology, it sure fits the description about right, so I thought I'd mention it.

I've seen in used for real-time trading systems in international dealing rooms. However, keep in mind that Excel is not a tool to expect true realtime performance from. It is more about near-realtime visualization + custom business logic in Excel.

From Wikipedia:

> [A common use of DDE is for custom-developed applications to control off-the-shelf software. For example, a custom in-house application might use DDE to open a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet and fill it with data, by opening a DDE conversation with Excel and sending it DDE commands. Today, however, one could also use the Excel object model with OLE Automation (part of COM). The technique is, however, still in use, particularly for distribution of financial data.[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange)

Also: on Joel Spolsky's old forum:

> [The data comes in way too fast an furious for SOAP. Anyway, the data is push, not pull, so SOAP doesn't really cut it. Most of the vendors on Windows give you a DDE server. Since it uses Windows messages for IPC at the lowest level, it's screamingly fast, which it needs to be to keep up with today's ticker.](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware4/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=118920)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked COM interop with Excel?  These classes seem to have [first-class wrappers for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but you should be able to access them from C++ with a bit of work.

Note that you may still pay for marshalling to Excel as `std::vector<>` is not compatible with the COM binary API.

Comment: But with ATL you'll have adaptor classes that expose any STL container as an IEnum with IDispatch and all. Perfect for your garden variety VBA clients